# SQL - Perform a count statement using a date range temp table and a list of customers with start/end contract date (2nd temp table)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image: Screenshot] - I'm currently trying to perform a count function using information coming from two temp tables. One table has only a list of dates Jan 1 2018 - Dec 31 2018 (temp table 1), and another table has customer info, approx 100 customers (temp table 2), including contract start and end dates. These two tables cannot be joined. My goal is to perform a count for each date in temp table 1, for example: if temp table 1 date is 1/1/2018 , I'd like to count how many contracts were active on that day, if a customer contract start date is 12/5/2017 and end date 12/31/2021 I want that customer to be counted, and so on. If customer contract date ends on 12/31/2017, I do not want that customer to be counted for 1/1/2018, if customer start date is 1/2/2018, I do not wish to count that customer on 1/1, only 1/2 and on. I hope this is enough info. Thank you

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words when it comes to SQL questions on Stack Overflow.  That being said, if you could show us sample tables both of input and output data, it would greatly help your question.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried. And why can't the two tables be joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have table structures as follows :

- table `customers` : has columns `start_date` and `end_date`, that represent the start and end date of the contract.
- table `dates` : has a column called `my_date`
- (and also assuming that all above columns are of datatype `DATE` or equivalent)

Then you want to `JOIN` both tables like :

```
SELECT
    d.my_date,
    COUNT(*) -- number of active contracts at that date
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN dates d ON d.my_date BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date
GROUP BY d.my_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Select mydate,Count(*) as activecount from tab2

where mydate > (select startdate from tab2)

and mydate <(select enddate from tab2)

group by mydate